# Python multiprocessing/threading with shared variables that only will be read

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Considering the code below. I would like to run 3 experiments at a time. The experiments are independent, the only thing they share is the Model object which they only read.

As there are seemingly no hard things in threading this out, how can I best do this in Python? I would like to use a pool or so to make sure that only three experiments run at a time. Shall I use multi-processing? If yes, how is the shortest and most concise?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import time

class Model:
    name = ""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Experiment:
    id = 0
    model = None
    done = False

    def __init__(self,id,model):
        self.id = id
        self.model = model

    def run(self):
        for _ in range(0,60):
            print "Hey %s from experiment %d" % (self.model.name, id)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.done = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    experiments = []
    model = Model("statictistical model")
    for i in range(0,5):
        experiments.append(Experiment(i, model))

    #How to run 3 experiments at the same time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs, specifically:

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

There really are a lot of examples there that should get you on your way. For instance, I could come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import time
import multiprocessing

class Model:
    name = ""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

def run_experiment(id, model):
    print "Experiment %d is starting" % id
    for _ in range(0,60):
        print "Hey %s from experiment %d" % (model.name, id)
        time.sleep(1)
    print "Experiment %d is done" % id
    return "Result for %d" % id


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = Model("statictistical model")
    experiments = ((i, model) for i in range(0, 5))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

    results = [pool.apply_async(run_experiment, experiment) for experiment in experiments]
    for result in results:
        r = result.get()
        # do something with r
        # or nothing, i suppose...
```

Do also pay attention to what the docs say about using the `multiprocessing` module:

> Functionality within this package
>   requires that the `__main__` method be
>   importable by the children. This is
>   covered in Programming guidelines
>   however it is worth pointing out here.
>   This means that some examples, such as
>   the `multiprocessing.Pool` examples
>   will not work in the interactive
>   interpreter

Answer (score 1):

You must always keep in mind that threads do not really run parallel, if that is what you actually want.

I do not unterstand what the actual problem is...? If you only want 3 threads running the same time, why not just start only 3 threads?

Comment: Why would threads not really run parallel on a multicore machine? And how would I check what threads are finished so that I can start an extra machine? A busy while loop would sound not very nice to me.

Comment: it has to do with the GIL (General Interpreter Lock) of Python. If you want further information about this topic, read here: http://dabeaz.com/GIL/

Comment: please check out the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive

Comment: ... unless Peter really is going to use multiprocessing (which will spawn new processes as threads instead of new 'threads') which Peter is asking if he should use (see http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)